# Exporting an HTML Canvas as Image

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I'm programmatically creating a very simple `HTML Canvas` on which I'm writing some text and then drawing an imported `PNG` Image.
I now want to "flatten" this canvas and export it out as a new Image.

It's working - but not 100%. 
The issue is that while the text and background colors DO show up in the newly created and exported PNG, the *image* that was  imported and drawn on the original canvas is NOT showing up.

Here's my code:

```
        var newCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        var context = newCanvas.getContext("2d");

        // 1. Filling Canvas with Background Color:
        context.fillStyle = "blue";
        context.fillRect(0, 0, newCanvas.width, newCanvas.height);

        // 2. Writing Text on the Canvas:
        context.font = "30px Comic Sans MS";
        context.fillStyle = "yellow";
        context.textAlign = "center";
        context.fillText("Hello World", newCanvas.width/2, newCanvas.height/2); 

        // 3. Adding a PNG to the Canvas:
        let bgdImage = new Image();
        bgdImage.src = "images/TilePattern1.png";
        
        bgdImage.onload = function(){
            context.drawImage(bgdImage, 0, 0, bgdImage.width, bgdImage.height);
        }


        // 4. Now I create a NEW Image object and set its contents to be 
        //    all those elements I drew on my Canvas:
        let finalImage = new Image();
        finalImage.src = newCanvas.toDataURL();
```

So the resulting `finalImage` created by this code DOES have both the Background color and the Text I wrote - but it does NOT have the "TilePattern1.png" IMAGE I imported and drew on the canvas using `.drawImage`

What do I need to do to fix this?

(NOTE: the imported "TilePattern1.png" image *DOES* show up in the canvas drawn on the **webpage**; but it does NOT show up on the Image exported from the Canvas.)

Comment: The duplicate question solves half of the problem only (waiting for image load) so I'm voting to reopen in the hopes someone can explain better than I why local files may not be loaded this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you have an error situation:

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL)

> SecurityError
> The canvas's bitmap is not origin clean; at least some of its contents
> have or may have been loaded from a site other than the one from which
> the document itself was loaded.

UPDATE: I have now run your code fully and the first problem is that you are not waiting for the image to be loaded before creating the base64 from the canvas so it doesn't have the image in it. The second problem is that if you wait for the image to be loaded and then attempt to create the base64 you will see something like this error:

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on
> 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported.

Here's the code which waits for the image to load so you can try for yourself:

```
 <body>
 <img />
 <script>
 var newCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        var context = newCanvas.getContext("2d");

        // 1. Filling Canvas with Background Color:
        context.fillStyle = "blue";
        context.fillRect(0, 0, newCanvas.width, newCanvas.height);

        // 2. Writing Text on the Canvas:
        context.font = "30px Comic Sans MS";
        context.fillStyle = "yellow";
        context.textAlign = "center";
        context.fillText("Hello World", newCanvas.width/2, newCanvas.height/2); 

        // 3. Adding a PNG to the Canvas:
        let bgdImage = new Image();
        bgdImage.src = "images/TilePattern1.png";
        
        bgdImage.onload = function(){
            context.drawImage(bgdImage, 0, 0, bgdImage.width, bgdImage.height);



        // 4. Now I create a NEW Image object and set its contents to be 
        //    all those elements I drew on my Canvas:
        let finalImage = new Image();
        finalImage.src = newCanvas.toDataURL();
        // below added so we can see the canvas and the final image (if you comment out the above line)
        document.body.appendChild(finalImage);
        document.body.appendChild(newCanvas);
        }
        </script>
        </body>
```

Comment: I understand what you're saying but both the image (".png") file and the HTML file that I'm loading are local files. As-in, sitting in a folder on my computer's desktop. So neither is remote. And my Console shows no errors. So I'm not sure that's the issue I've got happening here.

Comment: You are not seeing an error because at the time you are creating the base64 image the png has not been loaded and written to the canvas, so the canvas is clean. Put that creating of finalImage into the function that is called when the image has been fully loaded and you will see something like this error::   Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported.

Comment: I updated my answer with the changed code. If I run this on my webserver with the image stored at the same place then all is well. You aren't going to be allowed to 'see' the inside of a local file (security issue). Try putting your code and the image on an https server.

Comment: Yep - you're right! That was it.  Working beautifully now. Thanks a million - really appreciate it!